# Geopandas shows points outside of buffer geometry even though inside

Tags: python, shapefile, geopandas, shapely, trajectory

I have some ship trajectories and I want to know which point of the trajectory is **inside** the port(=buffer) and which points are ***outside***. The following picture shows my Geopandas Dataframe with the geometry.

The problem is that some points that are *inside*, are shown as *outside*. The problem can be easily seen if I use a **huge** buffer.

[image]

After that I am loading the port's point and buffing it, like below.

[image]

And then I am finding which points are inside and which outside, with the code below.

[image]

Now if I use a huge buffer, the are still rows in the ***points_outside_geometry*** dataframe. These rows shouldn't be tracked as outside points and this can be verified by the following plot.

[image]

[image]

How is that possible?

Code:

```
polys = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file('final_port.shp').buffer(100000)
sindex = gdf.sindex
points_within_geometry = pd.DataFrame()


for poly in port_poly:

    possible_matches_index = list(sindex.intersection(poly.bounds))
    possible_matches = gdf.iloc[possible_matches_index]
    precise_matches = possible_matches[possible_matches.intersects(poly)]
    points_within_geometry = points_within_geometry.append(precise_matches)

points_within_geometry = points_within_geometry.drop_duplicates(subset=['MMSI', 'TIMESTAMP'])
points_outside_geometry = gdf[~gdf.isin(points_within_geometry)].dropna(how='all')
```

Comment: @user2856 I updated the code. One question, the problem as stated in the referred question is on the alignment but in my question the intersection() parameter is a buffed point. Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you define `gdf`? There is one buffer in the image. Does `port_poly` contain one port (one record)?

Comment: If `points_within_geometry ` has duplicate records, and If you try to get points outside after dropping duplicates, that means `points_outside_geometry` includes duplicate ones already dropped .